# $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

As the title suggests, is $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly, for the purposes of this problem $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, has been defined as the set of all $2 \times 2$ integer matrices $A$ with $\det(A) = 1$. If this is the case, then you are basically asking how to justify  $A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \Rightarrow A^{-1} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. The point being that integer matrices of arbitrary determinant can have noninteger inverses, e.g. $(2I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{2} I$. Can you clarify your question a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a group, and it's certainly a subset of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, so yes it's  a subgroup.

Comment: *and the group operation is the same :)